# Folder and Subfolder Google drive permission

Tags: permissions, directory, google-drive-api, subdirectory

I have question about google drive.
If I have main folder Car, then the subfolders are Audi,Honda, Toyota, also Sold.
so everytime the buyer move the car what they want to "Sold" folder, they have no longer "edit or move" access about that car.
So the Maine folder car has "can edit" permission, but the subfolder " Sold" only has a "Can View" permission. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is not possible to have those access for the subfolder.
The best thing you can do is give the access for the main folder (Anyone who has the link can view or edit, then just create that "Sold" folder inside the main folder to be private and give the access for them.) Hopefully it helps